# Whilst forcing www with htaccess unwanted variables of the rewritten url show

Tags: .htaccess

I made a change to my .htaccess and the URL stopped rewriting properly. Currently looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to make "www" always appear, and it works, but the urls now look like:

```
http://www.e/example/es/1-bienvenidos?lang=es&id=1
```

Instead of

```
http://www.e/example/es/1-bienvenidos
```

This is the rest of the config section:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(en|es)/([0-9]+)-(.+)/?$ content.php?lang=$1&id=$2
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is the redirect rules before or after your other rules?

Comment: Jon Lin thanks for your comment, the redirect rules (force www )is after the other rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the redirect rules (force www )is after the other rules

You need to have your redirect rules **before** any routing rules. Rules that route requests through things like a `content.php` file will negate the point of externally redirecting.